# How to calculate model residuals from MCMCregress

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm doing classwork using Bayesian inference. For this, I'm using the `MCMCregress` function, from `MCMCpack`.  The problem comes when I want to get the residuals, because the function doesn't provide them, so I have to calculate them "by hand" (in R).

My model is:

```
Model <- MCMCregress(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5, data=DATA)
```

where `X1` and `X5` are continuous, while `X2`, `X3` and `X4` are dichotomous. The model output provides me the estimate for each variable:

```
(Intercept) = 1.90, 
X1 = -0.02, 
X2 = -0.05, 
X3 = 0.32,
X4 = 0.61,
X5 = -0.003,
sigma2 = 0.54
```

I think I have to so something like:

```
1.90 - 0.02*X1 - 0.05*X2 + 0.32*X3 ...
```

But I know that I'm missing something important in the R code, so I would like to know which is the correct R code in order to get residuals.

---

Here is  a reproducible example (although it does not correspond to the original data):

```
Y  <- c(0.2,0.8,1,4.3,5,3.5,3.2,1,3.3,1,2,4,3.6,3,5,4.3,3.2,4,1,2)
X1 <- c(17,13,15,NA,12,24,15,NA,12,22,14,12,18,NA,10,13,12,11,26,10)
X2 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA,NA)
X3 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,NA,0,NA,NA,0,1,0)
X4 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,NA,0,NA,NA,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
X5 <- c(2.46,4.56,32.1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3.76,5.67,4.56,NA,
        17.32,12.2,4.56,7.2,1.2,NA,9.2)

X2 <- ifelse(X2 > 0, c("Yes"), c("No")) 
X3 <- ifelse(X3 > 0, c("Yes"), c("No")) 
X4 <- ifelse(X4 > 0, c("Yes"), c("No")) 

DATA <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)


library(MCMCpack)
MCMC <- MCMCregress(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5, data=DATA)
summary(MCMC)
```

How can I get the residuals?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I'm asking for R code, so I've added a reproducible example (I hope it is useful) so, when you want, you can migrate my question to the right place. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That's no problem, @Alien. We'll get this over there where someone can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that something terrible happens to the MCMC chain toward the end of
the runs -- check out `xyplot(MCMC,layout=c(2,4))`.  I don't know what
the problem is, you'll have to sort that out, but in the meantime I'm
going to use the median rather than the mean as the coefficient estimates.

```
coefs <- apply(MCMC,2,median)[1:6]
X <- model.matrix(~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5, data=DATA)
pred0 <- X %*% coefs
```

The most complicated part is dealing with NA values: this is built into
most of the existing residuals() methods ...

```
pred <- napredict(attr(na.exclude(DATA),"na.action"),pred0)
resids <- pred-DATA$Y
```

Note that in this case, once NA values are removed, you're fitting a 5-parameter regression model to 6 complete observations.  You'll probably have to do something sensible with imputation to get any kind of reasonable answer ...

Comment: Your help was very useful (just what I was looking for), but the NA number was too high, so many residuals couldn't be calculated (so a lot of information was missed). Finally, I opted for data imputation.